# List all available packages of a PPA without accessing the launchpad page?

Tags: package-management, ppa

Is there a way to list all available packages of a PPA, before installing of any packages ? I mean, is `apt-cache` able to tell this, or any other methology ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Synaptic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/synaptic/) , you can see the respective available packages from the Selected PPA as here. You can select and Deselect to install and remove them. Also lists if an updated version is available.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Install `y-ppa-manager`. To do this, open a terminal and run these commands

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

In the y-ppa-manager window, there is a `List packages in a PPA` option. click on that option and enter a PPA name. All package name should be displayed immediately. Here is a [good link](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/05/y-ppa-manager-one-stop-shop-for-all.html) about this app.

[image: image of y-ppa-manager]

image credit goes to original author of the link site

**Note:** The benefit of this software is that, you can see available packages in a PPA without even enabling that.